# Conditional statement not running in swift tableView function despite having condition met?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am coding an app that appends strings to an array based on results from a DB query. I know the query and the appending and the resulting display iteration work fine because if I give the query a .whereKey to match a value that I know is in the DB, everything works fine. I have a conditional statement set up, though, incase the array that is appended has a count of 0 (indicating the query had matched no results). I have printed the amount to the log, and it is telling me it is indeed 0, but for some reason the code won't run. Below is the relevant code.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell

        // Configure the cell...
        if nameArray.count != 0{
            myCell.nameLabel.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
            myCell.creatorLabel.text = creatorArray[indexPath.row]
            myCell.typeLabel.text = typeArray[indexPath.row]
            myCell.locationLabel.text = locationArray[indexPath.row]

        } else if nameArray.count == 0{ 
            myCell.nameLabel.text = "None found. Please modify your search options"
            myCell.creatorLabel.text = ""
            myCell.typeLabel.text = ""
            myCell.locationLabel.text = ""
            print("It was 0")
        }
```

The nameArray is always appended if the query finds matching values. When I purposefully make it not, it will return a count of 0. Yet the lower conditional (was initially just an else{} but I made it specific just to check if for some reason that was the problem) does not run. The print statement is not even returned to the log. myCell is configured fine and the custom class cell also works well, so those are not the issue.

Comment: Did you check the array count by logging it outside of `if-else` loop and see what it print for each row?

Comment: @Khundragpan yeah I have a print statement at the end of the query (I have a function that queries and then appends the data which is run during viewDidLoad(). I printed the count to the log there and it prints 0.

Comment: What are you returning for number of rows in section? If you are returning `nameArray.count` and `nameArray.count == 0` then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will not be called because no cell needs to be dequeued.

Comment: @beyowulf that fixed it. I forgot to set a conditional to return 1 if `nameArray.count` was equal to 0 in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. That fixed it. Thank you.